# Has anyone ever claimed a warranty on an SSL certificate?

Tags: https, security-certificate

SSL certificates often advertise varying amounts of warranties or guarantees, for example $500,000 or $1m.

My question is, in the history of SSL, has anyone ever actually successfully claimed one of these warranties?  If not, is it fair to assume they are just marketing gimmicks?

Comment: Are you looking for a specific example because you need to cite one(in general, people probably wouldn't want to talk about it, I'd say) or are you actually questioning that the guarantee is real(which is sort of more a contract question or something)? I actually can't immediately think of a case where it would even come up. Most major e-commerce scandals seem to have involved the site allowing access to the user data, not failure of the SSL certificate itself, which is what's covered by what you're asking about.

Comment: Although it is an interesting question, it doesn't fall under "a website you control" and thus is off topic.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, the [security SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/) site crowd might find this interesting.